# * Sized columns not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am trying to print a page.

Here is my code:

```
private void Print(object obj)
{

    PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
    //if (dialog.ShowDialog() != true)
    //{ return; }

    Grid HaemogramReport = new Grid();

        RowDefinition rowTopMargin = new RowDefinition()
        {
            Height = new GridLength(198)
        };
        RowDefinition rowPatientDetails = new RowDefinition()
        {
            Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
        };
        RowDefinition rowReportHeader = new RowDefinition()
        {
            Height = new GridLength(66)
        };
        RowDefinition rowBody = new RowDefinition()
        {
            Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star)
        };
        RowDefinition rowBottomMargin = new RowDefinition()
        {
            Height = new GridLength(132)
        };

        HaemogramReport.RowDefinitions.Add(rowTopMargin);
        HaemogramReport.RowDefinitions.Add(rowPatientDetails);
        HaemogramReport.RowDefinitions.Add(rowReportHeader);
        HaemogramReport.RowDefinitions.Add(rowBody);
        HaemogramReport.RowDefinitions.Add(rowBottomMargin);

        Grid Head = new Grid();                

            Grid.SetRow(Head, 2);

            ColumnDefinition colLeftMargin = new ColumnDefinition()
            {
                Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
            };
            ColumnDefinition colHead = new ColumnDefinition()
            {
                Width = GridLength.Auto
            };
            ColumnDefinition colRightMargin = new ColumnDefinition()
            {
                Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
            };

            Head.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colLeftMargin);
            Head.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colHead);
            Head.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colRightMargin);

            TextBlock txtblockReportHeader = new TextBlock()
            {
                FontSize = 24,
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                Text = "HAEMOGRAM REPORT",
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
            };

            var measures = MeasureString(txtblockReportHeader);

            Rectangle rectReportHeader = new Rectangle()
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Width = measures.Width + 15,
                Height = measures.Height + 3,
                RadiusX = 7,
                RadiusY = 7,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
            };

            Grid.SetColumn(rectReportHeader, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(txtblockReportHeader, 1);

            Head.Children.Add(rectReportHeader);
            Head.Children.Add(txtblockReportHeader);

        HaemogramReport.Children.Add(Head);

    HaemogramReport.Measure(new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
    HaemogramReport.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), HaemogramReport.DesiredSize));

    dialog.PrintVisual(HaemogramReport, "Haemogram Report");
}

private Size MeasureString(TextBlock textBlock)
{
    var formattedText = new FormattedText(
        textBlock.Text,
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(textBlock.FontFamily, textBlock.FontStyle, textBlock.FontWeight, textBlock.FontStretch),
        textBlock.FontSize,
        Brushes.Black);

    return new Size(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height);
}
```

Here is Print :

[image]

I want the rectangle and the textblock to be horizontally centered. But I think * sized columns are not working as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got it.

I have to set the width of the grid to the width of the printable area.

Here is the code:

```
Head.Width = dialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
```